# Wordpress Child Theme Not Updating

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with Wr Nitro child theme. I have created the functions.php file, but all modifications are not showing up in the platform. I've already tried everything, cleared the cache, updating woocommerce files, but no results.
There's my function.php code:

```
function wr_nitro_child_enqueue_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_style('wr-nitro-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
} add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wr-nitro_child_enqueue_scripts', 1000000000 );
```

Comment: did you activate debug mode?, is anything there related to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

you have different functions inside add_action and as a function name.
wr_nitro_child_enqueue_scripts vs wr-nitro_child_enqueue_scripts
I suggest always copying function and variable names instead of writing them.